# Add labels to vertex by matching ID in a frame to the vertex names?

Tags: r, igraph

I have an igraph where the vertexes only have their IDs (`V(g)$name`). I also have a data.frame in this format that match each ID to a name:

```
ID   name
1    Ann
2    Bob
3    Carl
...
```

I would like to add the names to the vertex `(V(g)$label`) by matching the ID. The graph does not have all the IDs the names frame has.

I think it should be rather simple but as I'm new to R I'm not quite sure as how to do it.

Comment: Try using `?match`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, `match` could do the trick:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
ID   name
1    Ann
2    Bob
3    Carl
4    Linda
5    Peter")
library(igraph)
g <- sample_pa(4)
V(g)$label <- as.character(df$name[match(V(g), df$ID)])
```